# Тестирование в Java

Tags: java, тестирование

Начнём с того, что я новичок, пользуюсь IDEA. Интересуюсь, как разработкой оффлайн приложений, так и web-, даже про Android был бы не против, что-нибудь услышать, хотя и меньше, чем про первые два варианта. Напишу сначала, что я знаю о тестировании:

1) В некоторых книгах (и не только) рекомендуется такой подход к программированию, при котором перед тем, как писать непосредственно код, пишутся тесты. Если я правильно понял, тесты пишутся ко **ВСЕМ** классам, которые будут в коде. Но во первых, написание теста к классу требует такого же времени, что и написание самого класса, а иногда и гораздо большего. Во вторых, в тех ситуация, которые я учёл, класс будет функционировать исправно (за исключением опечаток), а в тех ситуациях, которые я не учёл, тест будет проходится успешно (т.к. они не заложены в тест). И в третьих, иногда не знаешь как будет выглядеть некий класс, до тех пор, пока его не реализуешь, более того, и после реализации будет много раз видоизменятся, иногда кардинальным образом - например: попробовал один подход - скорость отработки низкая, попробовал совершенно другой (с другим набором классов и интерфейсов) - выше.

- Так вот стоит ли прибегать к такому подходу? И как быть с учётом всего, выше написанного? Меня как-то панический страх берёт писать тесты все геттеры/сеттеры...

2) Слышал про автотестирование... даже видел обрывок записи, где записывался макрос мыши, как для автоматической прокачки персонажа в играх. Но знаю крайне мало, то, что мне попадалось выглядит сложно и непонятно, а самое главное не ясно, нужно ли это вобще...

- Просветите, как новичку воспользоваться автотестированием в различных ситуация (офф, web)? Какие программные инструменты для этого использовать? Какой русскоязычной литературой можно руководствоваться?

3) Может я ещё что-то упустил в области тестирования... Буду рад любым наставлениям ;)

Comment: В дополнение к ответу @DreamChild:

> Но во первых, написание теста к классу требует такого же времени, что и написание самого класса, а иногда и гораздо большего.

1. ![](https://www.simple-talk.com/iwritefor/articlefiles/1417-image001.jpg)
2. Обычно (у меня, во всяком случае) длительное написание теста получается из-за отлова недоловленных багов.

> а в тех ситуациях, которые я не учёл, тест будет проходится успешно (т.к. они не заложены в тест).

Ява типизированный язык, там сложно предположить какой-то неучтенный ввод. Если сложно представлять возможный ввод, тестируйте каждую ветку if.

Comment: > Слышал про автотестирование... не ясно, нужно ли это вобще... Просвятите, как новичку воспользоваться автотестированием в различных ситуация (офф, web)? Какие программные инструменты для этого использовать?

Selenium + наверняка есть аналог Codeception, но для явы. На правильное написание такого теста действительно может уйти уйма времени, но это незаменимый инструмент в CI для веб-приложения. Имея тест на каждый кейс или страницу и регулярно прогоняя их, можно быть уверенным в том, что какое-нибудь модальное окно не выпало и пользователь все еще способен выполнять все возможные действия.

Comment: А есть автотестирование для не веб приложений (оффлайновых)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> есты пишутся ко ВСЕМ классам

писать тесты абсолютно на все - не самая здравая идея.

> в тех ситуация, которые я учёл, класс будет функционировать исправно

не факт. У вас же нет никакой гарантии, что вы правильно  реализовали "то, что учли". Проверить это как раз помогут тесты

> в тех ситуациях, которые я не учёл, тест будет проходится успешно (т.к. они не заложены в тест)

разработчик обязан знать, что должен делать тот или иной его класс, соответственно, тестировать свои классы он должен на предмет соответствия этому "предназначению". Следовательно, описанная вами ситуация не имеет смысла

> иногда не знаешь как будет выглядеть некий класс, до тех пор, пока его не реализуешь

см. выше - разработчик должен знать, что будет делать создаваемый им класс, и тестировать его именно с этой точки зрения. Следовательно, тестированию не особо интересны детали реализации этого класса (и возможные изменения в этой реализации)

И наконец, не сочтите за занудство, но выглядит ужасно:

не "координальным", а  **кардинальным**, и не "просвятите", а **просветите**

Comment: > не "координальным", а кардинальным, и не "просвятите", а просветите

исправил.

> разработчик обязан знать, что должен делать тот или иной его класс

класс может очень часто меняться в силу того, что допустим заказчик часто приходит и говорит, что теперь он хочет совсем по другому или не удалось сделать какую-то часть задуманным образом.

Comment: Вот пример: Представление сделано на fxml. Я совершенно не ожидал, что после одного изменения размера окна у экземпляра Stage, перестанут автоматически устанавливаться размеры окна при смене сцены на соответствующие новой сцене (как это было до этого). В итоге, совершенно неожиданно, всем моим контроллерам пришлось реализовывать новый интерфейс (получения размеров окна из fxml-файла) и я не могу сказать, что это уж больно редкий случай.

Comment: @Andrey759 ну в любом случае невзирая на изменения логики разработчик всегда должен четко осознавать, что делают его классы

Comment: > писать тесты абсолютно на все - не самая здравая идея.

как понять к каким классам стоит писать тесты, а к каим нет?

Comment: исходя из логики. Вы же, по всей вероятности, хотите писать тесты ради надежности вашего ПО, а не потому что это модно. Выделите (я еще раз указываю на это) то, какой функционал вы желаете видеть в своем приложении, на какие классы возлагается ответственность по реализации этого функционала, и тестируйте на предмет соответствия/несоответствия вышеозначенным требованиям

Answer (score 4):

Важна мера во всем. Тестируются обычно сложные случаи. А так вообще все тестировать никаких сил не хватит. Потом ведь надо будет писать тесты тестов (я серьезно).

К тому же тестирование бывает разным: юнит тесты, нагрузочное тестирование, функциональное тестирование и т.д. Не зря среди прогерской братии есть специальность тестировщик/тестер.

Прогер должен тестировать конечный результат своего труда. Скажем написали некий класс/иерархию выполняющую допустим скачивание контента из сети. Логичным было бы написать юнит тест проверяющий идентичность скачанного со скачиваемым. В общем идея проста:

1. Вам мудрое руководство поставило некую задачу;
2. Вы ее решили;
3. Теперь надо доказать, что решение работает. Для этого пишете юнит тест (серию юнит тестов) доказывающих работоспособность вашего решения;
4. Показываете руководителю;
5. Профит.

P.S. Касательно бинов. Если вам поставили задачу написать бины - значит придется писать юнит тесты на ваши бины. Такова се ля ви :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот хороший плагин для Eclipse, который определяет уровень, насколько ваш код покрыт тестами. http://eclemma.org/